# R: erase duplicated element across columns, keep first ocurrence and relocate values

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a large dataframe with many columns that contains emails. Those emails sometimes are duplicated across columns in the same row. I'm trying to find a way to remove the dups and also relocate values to fill the gap left by the removed value.

All the things I've found on this topic in the last hours deal with duplicated rows, but this is more like duplicated values across columns.

Here is a `data.frame` to test my idea:

```r
    data <- data.frame(V1 = LETTERS[1:4], V2 = c(NA, "F", NA, NA), V3 = LETTERS[4:1], V4 = c("A", "D", "B", "F"))
    data
  V1   V2 V3 V4
1  A <NA>  D  A
2  B    F  C  D
3  C <NA>  B  B
4  D <NA>  A  F
```

Here is the desired output:

```r
  V1  V2   V3   V4
1  A   D <NA> <NA>
2  B   F    C    D
3  C   B <NA> <NA>
4  D   A    F <NA>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R option with `apply`:

1. `unique(x[!is.na(x)])` gets the unique non-NA values: e.g., `A NA D A` becomes `A D`
2. `"length<-"(..., length(x))` assigns the lengths of the original vector (`x`) to the output. It does by padding NAs in the end: e.g., `A D` becomes `A D NA NA`.
3. `apply(data, 1, ...)` applies the above function on all rows (`MARGIN = 1`) of the data set.
4. `apply`'s output needs to be `t`ransposed, and assigned to the original data.frame (`data[] <-`) to keep the attributes of the original data set.

```r
data[] <- t(apply(data, 1, \(x) `length<-`(unique(x[!is.na(x)]), length(x))))

data
#   V1 V2   V3   V4
# 1  A  D <NA> <NA>
# 2  B  F    C    D
# 3  C  B <NA> <NA>
# 4  D  A    F <NA>
```

Comment: Nice answer! You can shorten it replacing `x[!is.na(x)]` by using `na.omit(x)`:

Comment: I'm getting `Error: unexpected input in "t(apply(data, 1, \"`

Comment: Oh, yeah, use `function` instead of \. This is because you \ was introduced quite recently